# SyntaxError: import not found: default when defining a js class

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, unpkg

I'm building a WordPress plugin. I have the following in a JavaScript file called demo-one.js:

```
import WooCommerceRestApi from "https://unpkg.com/@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api@1.0.1/index.js";

alert('Hello!');

class someClass {
    constructor() {
        alert("Hello again!");
    }
}

export default function(){
    var mySomeClass = new someClass();
}
```

... and I find that in my console, I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: import not found: default  |    demo-one.js:1:7

All the information on the `export` keyword that I could find online used free-floating values and functions, outside of a class, so I apologize for flying a bit blind.

I was pretty sure that I was correctly defining a default export, but it appears that I'm not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In such situation I would try `import * as WooCommerceRestApi from ...` or `import {WooCommerceRestApi} from ...`, always a guessing game

Answer (score 2):

To use `import` you have to register that JavaScript as a module:

```php
// Your regular enqueue here
wp_enqueue_script( 'myplugin.js.main', $url, [], $path );

// Add type="module" to your script tag.
// Before: <script src="myscript.js"></script>
// After:  <script src="myscript.js" type="module"></script>
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    // Replace "myplugin.js.main" with your asset's handler
    if ( $handle !== 'myplugin.js.main' ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    return sprintf( '<script src="%s" type="module"></script>', esc_url( $src ) );
}, 10, 3 );
```